# Simple way to parse string as a Logical Expression

Tags: php, string, expression

Is there in php something like this? If not, what is the best approach here?

```
parse_bool("1 > 2"); //returns false
parse_bool("'a' == 'a'"); // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [eval](http://www.php.net/eval) for this purpose.

However, it's ***extremely*** important to be aware of the potential risks involved, especially if you're parsing any form of user provided input. See the existing  [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php) question/answers for more information.